# Amazon AWS Dynamo get all attributes of single item?

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Looking to retrieve all the attributes associated with a single item located in a DynamoDB table. I have already mapped it and am just wondering what function/method to use. I've done mapper.scans and mapper.queries before, but nothing like this!

Any help would be appreciated. Working in swift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In cases where you don't know ahead of time what attributes an item might have, or items have dynamic attributes, you can use the Document API (use GetItem, or Query API directly) to retrieve the item as a `Map<String, AttributeValue>` where the key in the map is the attribute name and the value is the attribute value, including the type.

Comment: So I got the getItem() request working, now how do I put that into an array or dictionary? I'm trying the map function, however the result of the getItem is of type AWSDynamoDBGetItemOutput, and is killing me to work with!